# Visual Studio output path for .NET 5.0 on Windows

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-5

I am building a solution file with different projects. Two of these projects (let's call them A and B) target at

```
 <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
```

but one of them has

```
x64
```

in the output path while this is missing in for the other project. Any ideas what is causing the intermediate directory to be created?

Comment: Does one of your projects have a  `<RuntimeIdentifier>` property?

Comment: No, this node is not present in either of the solution files.

Comment: Right click on solution in Solution Explorer -> Configuration manager -> find your project and set `platform` right